# Why is updating the edge size causing the edges to disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sigma.js

We are upgrading from sigma v1 to sigma v2

I am using this react-sigma library: https://github.com/sim51/react-sigma

what I am trying to do is to change the size of the edge using a formula that we have, where it depends on minEdgeSize and maxEdgeSize

```
const size = minEdgeSize + (maxEdgeSize - minEdgeSize) * (e.weight?e.weight:0);
```

now the problem is,this causes the edges to disappear for some reason

this useEffect causes edges to disappear:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const {minEdgeSize, maxEdgeSize} = graphSettings;
        graph.updateEachEdgeAttributes((edgeId, e)=>{
            const size = minEdgeSize + (maxEdgeSize - minEdgeSize) * (e.weight?e.weight:0);

            return {
                ...e,
                size,
            };
        });
    }, [graphSettings.minEdgeSize, graphSettings.maxEdgeSize]);
```

and yes, the size here is a valid integer value

initially, here's how I add edges to the network:

```
visibleEdges.forEach((edge)=>{
        graph.addDirectedEdge(edge.source, edge.target, {type: 'arrow', color: 'rgb(94, 91, 91)', size: edge.size?edge.size:1});
    });
```

here's the sigma container:

```
<SigmaContainer
            settings={{
                nodeProgramClasses: {image: getNodeProgramImage(), circle: CircleNodeProgram},
                edgeProgramClasses: {
                    arrow: ArrowEdgeProgram,
                },
                ...graphSettings,
            }}
            style={{height: '500px', background: props.noBackground ? 'white' : mainBackgroundColor}}
        >
```

and I get the arrow program from here:

```
import ArrowEdgeProgram from 'sigma/rendering/webgl/programs/edge.arrow';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this was fixed by setting the weight attribute when creating the edge, going form this:

```
visibleEdges.forEach((edge)=>{
        graph.addDirectedEdge(edge.source, edge.target, {type: 'arrow', color: 'rgb(94, 91, 91)', size: edge.size?edge.size:1});
    });
```

to this:

```
graph.addDirectedEdge(edge.source, edge.target, {type: 'arrow', color: 'rgb(94, 91, 91)', weight: edge.weight || 0, size: getEdgeSize(edge)});
```

note: `getEdgeSize` is just a function I made to calculate size based on some variables I have.